# Facebook App Developer Logo is gone?

Tags: facebook-apps

Facebook has changed the developers app screens and now I can't find the normal logo image to upload.

I have a "**website platform**" and all they show me is this:

[image]

Where do I upload the 75x75 logo image for the authentication login page?

Website platform:

[image]

Comment: Answered here in Stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20992068/new-facebook-developers-website-how-to-change-the-image-of-the-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upload the 1024x1024 App Icon :

[image: App Icon Logo]